# Transaction aborted when trying to persist user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to save an user. The user entity and group entity has a bi-directional many-to-many relationship. However the groups are already saved in the database (only two though: administrator and user).

Here I just "fake" the group which already exists because I thought that would work. I can't add the `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to the user because then it would save the group again, causing duplicate data. How would I fix this?

From the EJB

```
public void persistAsUser(User user) {
    Group group = new Group(2L, "user");
    user.addGroup(group);

    userRepository.persist(user);
}
```

> javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a
>   new object was found through a relationship that was not marked
>   cascade PERSIST:

---

Here are the entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "app_user")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        public static final String ALL = "User.all";

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Integer age;
        private String username;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
        private List<Group> groups;

        ....

public void addGroup(Group group) {

    if (!getGroups().contains(group)) {
        getGroups().add(group);
    }

    if (!group.getUsers().contains(this)) {
        group.getUsers().add(this);
    }
}
}
```

and

```
@Entity
    public class Group implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String groupName;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="group_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
        private List<User> users;

       ....

}
```

Comment: can't you just not populate the groups property in the User entity?

Comment: But I am doing that? I have added a group to the user, but I don't persist it because it is already persisted in the database.

Comment: set groups to null, that's what I am saying

Comment: And then how would the user know which group he belongs to? How would JPA know how to map the userid and groupid in the join table?

Comment: Then what I would do is retrieve the group you want to add the user to, add the user, and persist the group. You obviously need to indicate cascading for merge in the Group -> User relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually happens when

- you have bidirectional associations that are not populated in both sides
- you have a managed (`User`) entity referencing an unmanaged one (`Group`).

If you don't want to persist `Group`, just set groups to null, as per in my comment.

However, if you want to associate the User to the Group, one option would be

1. `load` the `Group` you want to add the user to
2. Add the `User` to the `Group` and viceversa.
3. `merge` the Group

Remember to mark the Group -> User relationship as `CascadeType.MERGE`

Comment: I tried loading the group from the database as you said, then I added the group to the user and the user to the group. After that I persisted the user, without setting any cascade rules and it works. Seems like JPA is satisified with that, would you explain why? Probably because the Group is included in the persistence context that way?

Comment: I presume Hibernate knows how to associate the User to the Group once the Group is managed - in your code above, the Group is unknown to Hibernate. In this case cascading doesn't make sense because you don't want to cascade the Group but only letting know Hibernate how the User relates to it.

Answer (score 0):

By placing the mappedBy attribute in the User class, you are saying that the Group class is responsible for persisting the association.

Since the relationship is bi-directional, you can specify either side as the owning side of the relationship.

Try moving the mappedBy attribute to the Group class's ManyToMany annotation, and then persist the User as you were.

Comment: not sure about this. mappedBy defines the owner of the association, that is the one that contains the relationship field

Comment: I'm always confused by mappedBy, but I believe the mappedBy attribute goes on the inverse (non-owning) side of the relationship.

Comment: that's correct. It is a way of telling JPA where the mapping configuration for this association is. In this case it is correct as the owning side is represented by the users property in the Group entity.